# Bearer token is not valid when calling the graph API

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I would like to see full information on my users in the AD (users in groups, etc...)
I already have an application that signs in to AD and then I get a bearer token that has access to my azure blockchain workbench API and everything works fine.
The workbench API has a users endpoint but the information is limited, it has first name, last name, email etc... and I would like to know more.

When trying to call the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me endpoint with the bearer token that I already have it is invalid and I get:

```
{

    "odata.error": {

    "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",

    "message": {

        "lang": "en",

        "value": "Access Token missing or malformed."

    },

    "requestId": "47322d1e-24d5-4170-ace5-947a8725ec1c",

    "date": "2019-03-13T08:14:37"

    }

}
```

I also tried a different approach. I have a service principal and gave this service principal an windows active directory basic info on users privilege. I also gave it a Microsoft Graph privilege and also a privilege to mu blockchain app (not sure if I need to).

I call https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant-id}}/oauth2/token with the client credentials body and I get a bearer token. Now with this bearer token I get:

```
{

    "error": {

        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",

        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",

        "innerError": {

            "request-id": "2a7febaa-a6db-4770-a323-1971fa0bf863",

            "date": "2019-03-17T13:54:57"

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access token needs to be acquired for Microsoft Graph API as the resource.

In first approach, token that you already have for workbench api will not work for Microsoft Graph because that token is meant for Workbench API.. you can check this by looking at `aud` claim for that token. You can decode the token using https://jwt.ms

In second approach, token should work, as long as you specified the resource you're acquiring token for is `https://graph.microsoft.com` and not workbench API. If you still face issues, share the code you're using to acquire token or the decoded token itself (minus any sensitive info)

Comment: Eventually the second approach did work I just had to grant permission to a lot more user related access, thanks